# Using browser geolocation API in a NodeJS request

Tags: node.js, request, geolocation

With Chrome, you can define your position within the Dev Tools (More Tools > Sensor). I assume it is done by using the geolocation API. Is it possible to use it in a NodeJS request?

Comment: What do you mean with "NodeJS request"?

Comment: Well, I should have had just said a request done programatically. I mean, by code and not using a browser.

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip